# Running large pipelines on GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, dataflow

I want to scale on cloud a one off pipeline I have locally.

1. The script takes data from a large (30TB), static S3 bucket made up of PDFs
2. I pass these PDFs in a ThreadPool to a Docker container, which gives me an output
3. I save the output to a file.

I can only test it locally on a small fraction of this dataset. The whole pipeline would take a couple days to run on a MacbookPro.

I've been trying to replicate this on GCP - which I am still discovering.

- Using **Cloud functions** doesn't work well because of its max timeout
- A full **Cloud composer architecture** seems a bit of an overkill for a very straightforward pipeline which doesn't require Airflow.
- I'd like to avoid coding this in Apache Beam format for **Dataflow**.

What is the best way to run such a python data processing pipeline with a container on GCP ?

Comment: Is this a mapReduce kind of pipeline or is the idea that a single machine needs to go through all pdf's in a serial way? In other words: can step 2 be ran in parallel for each (batch of) pdf('s), because from the question it sounds like it can't.

Comment: Yes, definitely. I'm using python threading for that.

Comment: do you think a cloud function invocation per pdf file is an option in terms of timeout, memory and CPU constraints?

Comment: @al-dann, definitely a possibility. How would I go about that ? I'd need a script to loop around the files themselves, which would have to be a cloud function. Not sure Workflows can do that. I'd also like to send multiple pdfs at once, so would like to avoid

Comment: You might try a cloud function that is triggered by a `google.storage.object.finalize` event - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage - when a file/object is saved (copied in your case) into a storage bucket. One invocation per file/object, and file/object details are provided into the cloud function - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-event-driven-functions#background-functions A code example - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-helloworld-storage#code-sample

Comment: I think to read big files, Beam with Dataflow is more adapted. Dataflow will read your file and process it in parallel with autoscaling. There are too many impacts to rewrite your job’s logic with Beam Python sdk ?

Comment: Maybe you can also think about a Cloud run job.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'm just quite surprised GCP doesn't offer a simple product where I can run my code for days on end. Dataflow could do the trick, but really an overkill for what I want to do. Cloud run also has a low timeout

Comment: Do you have a container and do you need to run it for many hours/day to complete the operation?

Comment: Maybe other options to run your container and long running job : 


- Google App Engine : 24 hours Basic scaling
- Google Compute Engine : infinite (you manage the VM)

If 24 hours with App Engine is not sufficient in your case, Compute Engine can do the job

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed

Comment: The link to the documentation to deploy containers on VMs and MIGs : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers?hl=en

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I have one container and a python script which calls it. I could potentially containerize the python script too. It would need to run for at least a day, the data crunching is quite intensive

Comment: @MazlumTosun Compute Engine would require I do the infra setup, no ? It's something I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with.

Comment: My idea, directly from the former AI and Analytics BigBoss at Google Cloud (Lak). Use Vertex AI training job to run a container to perform thing (originally training a model, but you can do whatever you want in your container). And it can last more than 1 day. Happy hacking!! https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-run-serverless-batch-jobs-on-google-cloud-ca45a4e33cb1

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere ! Also saw your clever workaround here : https://medium.com/google-cloud/long-running-job-with-cloud-workflows-38b57bea74a5

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quality input. Still incredibly surprised GCP doesn't have an offer for a basic use case as mine.

Comment: Batch processing is no longer the trend. If it's a one-off process, use a VM, it's enough. If it's a recurrent use case, redesign it to make it more realtime and process smaller chunks of data in parallel, on serverless product and that take only a few minutes to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the useful comments in the original post, I explored other alternatives on GCP.

**Using a VM on Compute Engine worked perfectly**. The overhead and setup is much less than I expected ; the setup went smoothly.

Comment: As I proposed in a my previous comment :), it's cool you are solved your issue.

Comment: Exactly, thanks for the help Mazlum